# Primefaces datatable filter event or tap not working in mobile browser (iPhone, iPad & Android)

Tags: android, iphone, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I am working in jsf web application, here primefaces datatable filter is working fine but same application open in safari browser or chrome browser in mobile (like iPad,iPhone & Android).

The issue I am getting is, Primefaces datatable filter touch event is not working. Only one time on click of datatable filter keyboard appears but again I click on filter the keyboard not appears.

So datatable is working fine in jsf web application but not working in mobile browser i.e if we open the same web application in browser the filter event is not working.

Is there any restriction for datatable filter event in mobile device?

I used below code for datatable in xhtml:

```html
<p:dataTable id="dtCompList" widgetVar="companyListTable" paginator="true" value="#{companyListService}" filterEvent="keyup" filteredValue="#{companyListService.filteredComapnies}" var="comp" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rows="50" class="fixed-scrollbar"
selection="#{companyListService.selectedComapnies}" emptyMessage="No companies found." 
draggableColumns="true" style="margin: -10px!important;" multiViewState="true"
rowsPerPageTemplate="50,100" tableStyle="table-layout:auto; " resizableColumns="true" resizeMode="expand" lazy="true" >
```

I used below version for jsf web application,
Primefaces version 6.2

Comment: Works for me using the showcase (PrimeFaces 11) on an Android device. I suggest to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I just added code like this and it's working

```
$('.ui-column-customfilter').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('input[type=text]').focus();
})
```

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces are you using?

Comment: Version is 6.1.